# Which upgrades can be unlocked?

Tags: steam-monster-game

As you upgrade, you will unlock new upgrades. Which upgrades can be unlocked – and when?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the list of abilities and upgrades, with when they are unlocked.
[You can take a look at this Reddit thread for more information.](http://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/39i0qc/psa_how_the_monster_game_works_an_indepth)

## Before we begin...

I'm not using scientific notations, because they're plain confusing to compare with metric measurements (which increment in pretty much "every 3 powers of 10")...

k = Kilo = 1,000 (1 x 10<sup>3</sup>)
M = Mega/Million = 1,000,000 (1 x 10<sup>6</sup>)
B = Billion = 1,000,000,000 (1 x 10<sup>9</sup>)
T = Trillion = 1,000,000,000,000 (1 x 10<sup>12</sup>)

Also **base** obviously mean "the value at the very start of the game".

## Upgrades

**Note:** Health, Click and Auto-click (DPS) upgrades open up their next tier when the top-most unlocked tier is at Level 10.

**Health Upgrades:** (Your base health is: 1000)

- Tier 1: Light Armor (x1.3 everything per Level)
- Tier 2: Heavy Armor (+10k HP/Level)
- Tier 3: Energy Shields (+100k HPLevel)
- Tier 4: Personal Training (+1M HP/Level)
- Tier 5: Cybernetic Enhancements (+10M HP/Level)
- Tier 6: Exoskeleton (+100M HP/Level)
- Tier 7: Yoga Training (+1B HP/Level)
- Tier 8: Protein Shakes (+10B HP/Level)
- Tier 9: Martial Arts Training (+100B HP/Level)
- Tier 10: Seriously? Another AP Upgrade (+1T HP/Level)

**Auto-clicker Upgrades:** (Your base is: 10)

- Tier 1: Auto-Fire Cannon (+10 DMG/s/Level)
- Tier 2: Advanced Targeting (+100 DMG/s/Level)
- Tier 3: Farming Equipment (+1k DMG/s/Level)
- Tier 4: AFK Equipment (+10k DMG/s/Level)
- Tier 5: Level 1 Sentry Gun (+100k DMG/s/Level)
- Tier 6: Level 2 Sentry Gun (+1M DMG/s/Level)
- Tier 7: Level 3 Sentry Gun (+10M DMG/s/Level)
- Tier 8: Level 1 Drones (+100M DMG/s/Level)
- Tier 9: Level 2 Drones (+1B DMG/s/Level)
- Tier 10: Level 3 Drones (+10B DMG/s/Level)

**Click Upgrades:** (Your base DPC; damage-per-click is: 10)

- Tier 1: Armor Piercing Rounds (+10 DMC/Level)
- Tier 2: Explosive Rounds (+100 DMC/Level)
- Tier 3: Railgun (+1k DMC/Level)
- Tier 4: New Mouse Button (+10k DMC/Level)
- Tier 5: Titanium Mouse Button (+100k DMC/Level)
- Tier 6: Double-Barreled Mouse (+1M DMC/Level)
- Tier 7: Bionic Finger (+10M DMC/Level)
- Tier 8: Bionic Hand (+100M DMC/Level)
- Tier 9: Bionic Arm (+1B DMC/Level)
- Tier 10: [Name Unknown] (+10B DMC/Level)

**Miscellaneous Upgrades:** (Those that does not belong to an upgrade tree)

- Elemental Damage (unlocks at the very beginning)
- Lucky Shot (Unlocks when Armor Piercing Rounds is at Level 5)
- Boss Loot (Unlocks when Auto-Fire Cannon is at Level 10)

## Abilities

- Medics (Unlocks when Light Armor is at Level 1)
- Good Luck Charm (Unlocks when Armor Piercing Rounds is at Level 5)
- Tactical Nuke (Unlocks when Armor Piercing Rounds is at Level 10)
- Cluster Bomb (Unlocks when Auto-Fire Cannon is at Level 10)
- Napalm (Unlocks when Auto-Fire Cannon is at Level 10)
- Morale Booster (Unlocks when Auto-Fire Cannon is at Level 20)
- Decrease Cooldown (Unlocks at the start of the game)
- Metal Detector (Unlocks at the start of the game)

Comment: Base HP is 1k (1000) if it helps=)  Nice writeup.